# How does hibernate find the same object in same session if Id does not have equals

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Entity class which has a composite id and neither of the entity class or the composite id class override equals but findById(compositeId) returns the same object within the same session ,if the value of compositeId fields are same.
It could not be using some proxy to define equals because if it did that it would return the same object in a different session too but in a different session the returned result is not the same instance.

Code examples

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey implements Serializable{
    @NotBlank
    private String partKey1;

    @NotBlank
    private String partKey2;
//getter setter
```

}

Entity also does not have equals

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "testentity")
    public class TestEntity {

        @EmbeddedId
        private CompositeKey cid;

        @NotBlank
        private String otherFields;
//getter setter
}
```

Within the same session calls with different instances of CompositeKey return the same instance (if the value of fields of CompositeKey are same).
In a different session it returns different instance even if value of fields of CompositeKey are same
I can verify this by following snippet in a controller

```
  compositeKey=getNewCompositeKey(partKeyValue1,partKeyValue2)
     Optional<TestEntity> existing = TestEntityRepository.findById(compositeKey);
            if (existing.isPresent()) {
                TestEntity existing1 = existing.get();
                testEntitySet.add(existing1);
                //create a new key and use findById again
                //it gives the same instance if values of fields of
               //compositeKey are same
```

My question here is within the same session how does it find the same instance every time without an equals on the Composite Id class?

Answer (score 1):

Every class have default implementation of `equals` and `hashcode` originating from `Object` class.

Comment: But then every new instance of composite key will be unequal according to equals of Object class ,so how would find by composite key return the same instance of the entity?

Comment: Composites have special handling. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cache/CacheKey.html. In fact, I think that nothing stands in your way preventing you from actually stepping in into actual runtime implementation. As for the case, most obvious reason is to consider member of composite key to build a cache entry intseed of equals/hashCode methods.